# R While loop exiting in the middle of loop

Tags: r, while-loop, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to make a program that determines if a number is in a cluster based on a threshold. I need it to go through this while loop enough times to check all numbers and exit when only numbers not in the threshold are left.  I've been using Boolean values to determine this.  However, it seems to be that as soon as it's false the while loop stops.

Here's the while loop:

```
while(allInCluster){
     centroid <- mean(cluster)

     distance <- max(data)
     data <- c(newData)
     newData <- c()
     smallest <- data[1]
     allInCluster2 <- FALSE
     for(i in 2:length(data)){
       if((abs(centroid - data[i]) > distance) & (abs(centroid - data[i]) <= centroidThreshold)){
         print("smallest")
         print(smallest)
         newData <- c(newData, smallest)
         smallest <- data[i]
         print("smallest changed")
         print(smallest)
         allInCluster2 <- TRUE
       }else{
         newData <- c(newData, data[i])
         allInCluster2 <- FALSE
       }
     }
     if(allInCluster2 == FALSE){
       allInCluster <- FALSE
     }
     cluster <- c(cluster, smallest)

     print("centroid")
     print(centroid)
     print("cluster")
     print(cluster)
     print("The other numbers")
     print(newData)
   }
```

Here's the sample data set I've been using:

```
data <- c(103,103,103,104,102, 102,102, 102,105,103, 110, 111)
```

with the threshold set to 5.

This is what it outputs:

```
[1] "cluster"
[1] 102 102 102 102
[1] "The other data"
[1] 103 103 103 104 105 103 110 111
[1] "centroid"
[1] 102
[1] "cluster"
[1] 102 102 102 102 103
[1] "The other numbers"
[1] 103 103 104 105 103 110 111
>
```

Comment: You have shared data for only `data` but may other vectors have been used in your code.

Comment: All the other vectors except cluster are declared in the while loop. At the beginning of the program cluster is declared as the number that appears the most, as many times as it appears, so in the case I shared it would be 102, 102, 102, 102 because 102 appears the most and it appears 4 times